# File cannot delete - java - opencsv

Tags: java, opencsv

I’m trying to delete a CSV file that has red by CSVReader object (comes with opencsv library). 
End of the file reading process, I wanted to delete it. So I’m trying it with `f.delete();`  (f is the file object) but It doesn’t working for some times. The CSVREader object has correctly closed with `reader.close();`.

I have tried this with a test java class and I deletes successfully .

**Test**

```
File f = new File(“E:\\LogData\\NewGlog_0001_20140202191120.csv”);
f.delete();
```

I feel it is a problem with the openCSV. plz help me.

Thank in advance.

Comment: What does f.exists() return?

Answer (score 1):

First, check your write permissions on the file (e.g. with `f.canWrite()`)

If you read a file you should then close it. Otherwise it stays in use.

Make sure reading the csv file has been [handled properly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), i.e.

```
try (Reader reader = openReader(..)) {

}
```

If you need it to remain open, you can use `file.deleteOnExit()` which will delete the file whenever the VM is shut down.